# Add SSL Cert to Net Core application in Windows VPS

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, .net-core, https

So,

I currently have a net core web api running in a windows VPS (amongst other things). When I make requests to this api, I would like to do so using https. It seems I need to have an SSL Cert on this VPS (which does not have a domain, just an IP).
The https API is on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443

The net core application is published into a self-contained package and run as an .exe (i think using IIS express)

Ideally I would like to use a free SSL cert from something like zerossl.com or any viable alternative you may suggest

How can I go about making it so that if I access xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443/api/values, I get a secured icon in my browser?

Thanks

Comment: what version of .net core you are using?

Answer (score 2):

> It seems I need to have an SSL Cert on this VPS (which does not have a domain, just an IP)

It is impossible to bind SSL Certificate to IP address.It must bind to domain.